Issue with Spring Microservice Gateway Behind WAF Using HTTPS
I have a Spring microservice project built using JHipster. My setup includes:
A gateway (client view) that I want to place behind a Web Application Firewall (WAF) with HTTPS enabled.
The gateway needs to call another set of microservices, which are in the WAF but use HTTP (not HTTPS).
The problem is that when the gateway sends a request to the microservices, the request does not reach the microservices and i get 403 error .
I've checked the following:
WAF rules and configurations.
HTTPS settings on the gateway and HTTP settings for the microservices.
Network connectivity between the gateway and microservices.
Another thing is when gateway is http everything work ok
Has anyone faced a similar issue or can guide me on how to troubleshoot this? Could this be related to WAF rules or mismatched protocols (HTTPS vs. HTTP)?
